# Bigquery and Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to use bigquery to query data from google cloud storage.

[image]

Those are the data for my real time DB in firebase. It consists of json file. How can I query through and see data inside each file?

I am actually reading through this but I don't understand how to connect.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage

Update

[image]

[image]

If I point to particular file (like firebase.json), it is okay. But i need to update my data.

[image]

Comment: What is unclear? What did you try?

Comment: I don't see document/tutorial how to connect to firebase realtime DB from bigquery (also to query files from Google Cloud Storage which firebase realtime DB backup automatically).

Comment: You can define a temporary or permanent external table over a JSON file stored on GCS, as described in the documentation that you linked.

Comment: How can I get JSON from .GZ file? It is because firebase automatically backup in that format. If possible, I need to tap data from firebase real time db directly.

Answer (score 2):

**Using UI by 2018-10-29**

If you want to do it from the UI. Go to bigquery, at the left click on your

```
project -> dataset -> at the right click on cleater Table
```

Fill the rest of the information

- Create table from: Google Cloud Storage
- Select from GCS bucket: path to your database location on GCS
- File format: JSON
- Under the schema section click auto detect schema

That should do the work using the new UI by 2018-10-29

**Using CLI**

You can do it from google console as well using bigquery CLI like

```
bq mk --external_table_definition=gs://yourbucket/path/yourdb --destination_format NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON --autodetect yourdataset.yourtablename
```

Last arguments is your dataset name dot your table name.

You don't need to specify a file, you can point to a folder. About compression, from BigQuery documentation

> If you use gzip compression BigQuery cannot read the data in parallel.
>   Loading compressed JSON data into BigQuery is slower than loading
>   uncompressed data.

So it is supported, but not recommended from a performance point of view due the limitations of the gz format, Anyway if should have several small files, it shouldn't matter, I think it is more related to big files gziped.

EDIT:
If you need to point multiple files, you can use wildcard like `--external_table_definition=gs://yourbucket/path/yourdb/*`

Comment: I think your solution will work. But may I know how to deal with .gz file? It is because firebase realtime db backup in that format and naming also will be different everytime.

Comment: you dont need to point to specific file,  I updated related to gz

Comment: Thanks. I will let you know again here once it is successfully connected.

Comment: I have updated question to add error image. I have done as in your suggestion. But it say Source URI must be ...... I think it is correct location already. May be permission error? How can I give permission to get access from bigquery?

Comment: are you using the new or old ui? for some reason I have a different view. did you try from the command line? In my case, the URI looks like "mybucket/myjson/part-*" without gs at the front. it could be error permissions, make sure that the bucket has read access for any user (at least for testing). You should be able to use the UI to explore the folder location, don't need to enter it manually